# Deploying destructive changes using SFDX with --sourcepath flag

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, metadata-api, ant, destructivechanges.xml

I've seen that finally destructive changes in SFDX deployments have been added - starting from version v53.0 (previously I needed to use ANT because of lack of this functionality).
I have tested this and found that if You are deploying destructive changes it is required to use --manifest flag.

*--manifest= must also be provided when using --postdestructivechanges=*

Problem is that my SFDX deployments are based on --sourcepath flag which indicates working directory to deploy (/src). And only one flag --manifest or --sourcepath flag is allowed to use.

*sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath src*

[image: Manifest]

Is it possible to deploy destructive changes when deploying source based on --sourcepath flag?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had the exact same issue, where we are using sourcepath for our deployments and we didn't want to use a package.xml for deployments. But using the create manifest command I managed to work around this, as this dynamically creates the manifest file from a sourcepath.

First create a manifest dynamically based on your SourcePath:

```
sfdx force:source:manifest:create --sourcepath force-app --manifestname manifest/deployPackage
```

The script above assumes the sourcepath to be: "force-app", where the complete directory is actually: "force-app\main\default" based on standard SFDX project creation. This command then creates a manifest in the folder: `manifest` named: `deployPackage.xml`. For more info see Salesforce documentation: [force:source:manifest:create](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_manifest_create)

Then use the source deploy command using just created manifest and include your destructive changes as well:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --manifest manifest/deployPackage.xml --predestructivechanges manifest/destructiveChangesPre.xml --postdestructivechanges manifest/destructiveChangesPost.xml
```

The `--manifest` command is pointing to the manifest created in the first command. In this case I am expecting that the `--destructiveChangesPre` & `--destructiveChangesPost` files are already available in the `manifest` folder. For more information see Salesforce documentation: [force:source:deploy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_deploy)